# Some elementary geometric inequalities of spinorial origin

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, spinor, geometric-inequalities

Let there be given $\psi_a \in S^3 \subset \mathbb{C}^2$ and $v_a \in S^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ for $a = 1, \ldots, 4$, which are assumed to satisfy the following relations:

$$ \psi_a \psi_a^* = \frac{1}{2}\left(\mathbf{1} + \sum_{i=1}^3 v_{ai} \sigma_i\right) $$

for $a = 1, \ldots, 4$, where $\psi_a^*$ is the complex conjugate transpose of $\psi_a$, $\mathbf{1}$ is the $2$ by $2$ identity matrix, $v_a = (v_{a1}, v_{a2}, v_{a3})^T$, with the $v_{ai}$ being real numbers and $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$ and $\sigma_3$ are the Pauli matrices.

Define
$$ \langle \psi_1 \odot \psi_3, \psi_2 \odot \psi_4 \rangle = \langle \psi_1, \psi_2 \rangle \langle \psi_3, \psi_4 \rangle + \langle \psi_1, \psi_4 \rangle \langle \psi_3, \psi_2 \rangle, $$

where $\langle ., . \rangle$ is the standard hermitian inner product on $\mathbb{C}^2$, assumed to be complex antilinear in the first argument and complex linear in the second argument (closer to Dirac's notation, rather than the usual convention in math circles), $\odot$ denotes the symmetric tensor product (over $\mathbb{C}$).

A calculation shows that
$$ 4 | \langle \psi_1 \odot \psi_3, \psi_2 \odot \psi_4 \rangle |^2 = 2 (1 + (v_1, v_2))(1 + (v_3, v_4)) + 2 (1 + (v_1, v_4))(1 + (v_2, v_3)) - (1 - (v_1, v_3))(1 - (v_2, v_4)), $$

where $(., .)$ denotes the Euclidean inner product in $\mathbb{R}^3$. In particular, we have that the RHS is non-negative, for any $4$ points $v_a \in S^2$ (for $a = 1, \ldots, 4$). This is an example of what I call an elementary geometric inequality of spinorial origin.

Of course, one could do a similar calculation for

$$|\langle \psi_1 \odot \psi_3 \odot \psi_5, \psi_2 \odot \psi_4 \odot \psi_6 \rangle|^2$$

and so on, involving an increasingly higher (even) number of $\psi$'s and $v$'s. One would then obtain higher and higher degree elementary geometric inequalities of spinorial origin involving the Gram matrix of the $v$'s.

Is anything known about such a sequence of geometric inequalities please? Is there a way, perhaps similar to Wick's theorem in QFT, to write down the RHS of such formulas? What is an alternative proof of the non-negativity of the RHS, involving say that the Gram matrix of the $v$'s is positive semidefinite? I think the main question I am interested in though is how to characterize the $v$'s for which the RHS vanishes (starting with the case I wrote down).

Edit 1: Let $\mathbb{M}$ denote $4$-dimensional Minkowski spacetime, with standard basis $e_0$ (timelike) and $e_i$, for $i = 1, \ldots, 3$ (spacelike). We think of the $v_a$ as sitting in the span of the $e_i$, for $i = 1, \ldots, 3$. We then let
$$ \begin{align*} n_1 &= e_0 + v_1 \\ n_2 &= e_0 - v_2 \\ n_3 &= e_0 + v_3 \\ n_4 &= e_0 - v_4 \end{align*}. $$
Note that since the $v_a$, for $a = 1, \ldots, 4$, are arbitrary points on $S^2$, it follows that the $n_a$ are arbitrary future pointing null vectors in $\mathbb{M}$, all having their "time" component equal to $1$ (of course, the latter condition can be relaxed by homogenizing $f$).

We then have that
$$ f(v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4) = 2(n_1, n_2) (n_3, n_4) + 2(n_1, n_4) (n_2, n_3) - (n_1, n_3) (n_2, n_4), $$
where $(., .)$ now denotes the Minkowski inner product (with the $(+, -, -, -)$ convention).

Note that this can be rewritten as:
$$ f(v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4) = 2 (n_1 \odot n_3, n_2 \odot n_4) - \lVert n_1 \odot n_3 \rVert \lVert n_2 \odot n_4 \rVert. $$
So this seems closely related to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, except that there is a mysterious factor of $2$ (which seems necessary, after some numerical simulations).

Edit 2: it turns out one can prove non-negativity of the RHS for the special case above using (drum roll):

1. a squared version of Ptolemy's inequality,
2. the formula $(n_a, n_b) = \frac{1}{2} d_{ab}^2$, where $d_{ab}$ is the chordal distance between $v_a$ and $v_b$, i.e.
   $$ d_{ab}^2 = \lVert v_a - v_b \rVert^2, $$
   where $\lVert . \rVert$ denotes the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^3$ and
3. the elementary formula $2 ab \leq a^2 + b^2$ if $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative real numbers.

It is also possible to characterize the equality case using the equality case of Ptolemy's inequality and the equality case of the elementary formula in 3.

I am still interested in higher degree cases though, especially in finding necessary and sufficient conditions on the $v$s so that the expression I have denoted by $f$ (or rather higher degree versions of it) vanishes.